# shouldAutorotate is not getting called although i have category for uinavigationcontroller to forward the call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, autorotate

I'm a little bit confused.
I want my app to rotate in exactly one of my 5 Viewcontrollers.
I created a Category for UINavigationcontroller implementing the necessary methods for rotating in ios 6.

```
#import "UINavigationController+IOS6Rotation.h"


@implementation UINavigationController (IOS6Rotation)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if (INTERFACE_IS_PAD) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }
    else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }    
}
@end
```

I also have implemented these methods in all my ViewControllers which should not rotate.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    if (INTERFACE_IS_PAD) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
    else{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

The one who should rotate returns YES in shouldAutorotate

On Startup, i use an extra Viewcontroller to show a Splashscreen. This SplashScreen is displayed as RootViewController like this.

```
vc_splash = [[SplashScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.window setRootViewController:vc_splash];

DefaultSHKConfigurator *configurator = [[MySHKConfigurator alloc] init];
[SHKConfiguration sharedInstanceWithConfigurator:configurator];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

When I'm finished loading my database, the splashscreen is exchanged for the mainscreen.

```
self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: self.viewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController: navControl];
```

Problem now is, that only my Splashscreen calls shouldAutorotate, but the other screens don't.
Can someone tell me if i have missed some essentials here?
I thought i had done all necessary stuff to get that bl****y autorotation to work correctly in ios 6...

Thx in advance,
Maverick1st

**update****
If you want your iPad to start in Landscape, be sure to return YES in your shouldAutoRotate,

Comment: Why did you implement a category for `UINavigatorController` when you implemented all of the methods in 4 of the 5 `ViewController`s anyway? I thought the point of implementing the category was to avoid having to duplicate code. Since you've gone this far, why not try implementing the three rotational methods directly in the `ViewController` that you want to rotate?

Comment: You need to forward the method call in the category, since the methods in the viewcontroller do not get called when the viewcontroller is contained in either a tabbarcontroller or a navigationcontroller. I already created an app using tabbar and navigationcontroller in the tabs and there it worked fine. It simply do not know what i have done wrong this time, since it should work properly in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is working for me add `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow`
 method in `application` `delegate`:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
  UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
  [navigationController shouldAutorotate];
  [navigationController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Also add this in `application` `delegate`:

```
@implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
  return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] shouldAutorotate];
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
  return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
@end
```

Comment: calling shouldAutorotate explicitly from supportedIntefaceOrientationsForWindow results in an infinit loop in my code.
I also do have already a category so i see no reason to implement a second one in appDelegate doing the same. Or is there a difference between [self.viewcontrollers lastObject] and self.topViewController ?

Comment: no differnce between [self.viewcontrollers lastObject]' and 'self.topViewController'. remove category from other viewcontroller and add only in appDelegate

Comment: but this does not solve the problem, that your code causes an infinite loop, since supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow keeps beeing called.

Comment: OK, now shouldAutorotate gets called correctly, but on ipad the app shows all screens in portrait instead of landscape. Even when i return landscape in preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation.
Any idea why this happens? The Xibs are all in landscape and the only supported orientation is landscape except for one viewcontroller.

Comment: THE ONLY WORKING SOLUTION OUT THERE!. thank you for posting this. Whenever you transition to a view controller, this method application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow gets called in appD. So call appD by doing [UIApplication SharedApplication] delegate] to change its value like appD.allowPortraite (BOOL) and you can work out all orientation changes

Comment: who ever downvoted can correct this answer or provide new answer as you have knowledge for better one.